# Update shrinkwrap.json after dependency is moved to devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

By mistake i did `npm i --save xxx` and my `shrinkwrap.json` was (correctly) written.

As i wanted actually to did `--saveDev` i started to explore solutions

Now my first idea was to do `npm uninstall --save xxx` but to my surprise library was removed from `package.json` but `shrinkwrap.json` was not written

Is there a way to revert this ?

thx

Comment: As long as you haven't committed the changes, you can easily use Git to get rid of them

Comment: Well thats the problem it is not really in the git yet so not viable option

Comment: You could always edit the shrinkwrap file yourself, it's human readable

Comment: Did you try running `npm shrinkwrap` after the dependency was removed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [this is a problem with certain versions of npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12642) - so you should try updating your local npm install.

If updating npm is not satisfactory, you could create a `postuninstall` script to automatically re-shrinkwrap every time a package is uninstalled:

```
"scripts": {
    "postuninstall": "npm shrinkwrap"
}
```